# Allow Windows file share through a Linux Firewall

Tags: linux, files, iptables, windows

I'm struggling to enable NTFS share between two Windows (XP and 7) hosts through a Linux firewall.

Here's my setup:

```
[XPMachine-LAN1]---------->[LINUX FIREWALL]---------->[Win7-LAN2]
```

What I want to do is to NAT the NTFS input from the XP machine to the same ports on the Win7 machine.

The problem is that when I try from the XP machine to open the network share `\\LINUXFIREWALL` then the firewall doesn't seem to be NATing the packets to the Win7 machine.

I've opened the standard NTFS/Samba ports like 135:139 and 445, some of them need UDP and the others TCP (details available on various sites).

However since I am running 2 different versions of windows I tried to google that to see if there would be a change between XP and 7 and that list is available on MS website :
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/Networking-home-computers-running-different-versions-of-Windows#section_2

My question is, if you are running 2 windows machine through a *nix box with iptables, can I ask what your iptables file looks like? Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post relevant rules in your `iptables`. And please provide some information on how do you come to know that firewall in not NATing the packets. More information you will provide better we can help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate...

Here is an example of the iptables rule I use :
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp --dport 137 -j DNAT --to 10.127.255.252:137

Comment: I am no iptables guru by any means, but I wrote the above rule a while ago to allow another network service on the exact same machines and it worked like a charm so I can't see why that same rule would not be suitable for NTFS shares...unless I don't have the complete list of all the ports involved....

Comment: I am guessing this is because the windows machine are running different versions of windows, XP and Seven, so the ports configuration looks a bit cranky here :
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Networking-home-computers-running-different-versions-of-Windows

Comment: But anyway, I am happy to deal with the MS side of things later.. For now I would really appreciate if someone can confirm that the iptables rule I am using here is suitable for that purpose, or if there's any better way to do it...

Thanks a lot for your help!

Bz.

Answer (score 1):

The answer had nothing to do with Linux.

On Windows 7, if your network type is "home" then you can only share files with other Windows 7 machines. In order to be able to send files to machines  running previous Windows versions you need to set your local network to "work".

It's not something I would have guessed, I bet I am not the only one here.